# 'Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site' while deploying to development site

Tags: sharepoint-addin

This error has been brought up several times before, however this context is unique.  I am aware that the following error:

> 'Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Sideloading of apps is not enabled on this site'

is usually shown when trying to deploy a SharePoint add-in to a non-development site.  Strangely, I now receive this error message while deploying to a development site, a site I have used to debug apps for months.  Does anyone know what might have changed to make this error appear, or where I can check the site type from the site settings?

Answer (score 2):

Side loading is controlled by the hidden feature `EnableAppSideLoading`, so you need Powershell access to check if the feature is enabled on the site collection (and enable it).

Here is a [MSDN blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/12/10/enable-app-sideloading-in-your-non-developer-site-collection/) on how to do it on Office 365.